# php move/copy image files to new directory/folder structure in linux

Tags: php, file, filesystems

I have a php/mysql website where users create listings and upload multiple images (3 image sizes for each).  I made the mistake of storing the images in folders as below :

```
images/listings/listing_id/image-name.jpg
images/listings/listing_id/thumbs/image-name.jpg
images/listings/listing_id/large/image-name.jpg
```

Unfortuantely now I have come across the problem where the maximum number of sub directories is 30,000 and my code breaks.

I want to now change my folder structure to the one below :

```
images/listings/yyyy/mm/dd/listing_id/image-name.jpg
images/listings/yyyy/mm/dd/listing_id/thumbs/image-name.jpg
images/listings/yyyy/mm/dd/listing_id/large/image-name.jpg
```

I decided the best way forward would be to create a php script to loop around all directories in the 'images/listings/' folder, and copy every image in to a new directory as specified above.  or each 'listing_id' folder, I would need to lookup using mysql the listing_id, and get the created_date and then split the date to get the yyyy mm dd.

I'm totally lost in creating the php script, would it be possible to rename the existing directory structure without copying and deleting the old images, or would I need to copy the  old images, create the new directories, move them and then delete the old folders?

Comment: where is your code so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as you don't have any listing_ids that are the same as a 4-digit year you should be able to create the new folder structure alongside the existing one.

You seem to already have a plan for how to do it, you should try actually writing some code.

Hint: [`rename()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) is the same as 'move'. Don't do "copy and delete" unless you want it to take 10x longer.

Lastly, as a rule of thumb you should try to avoid having *any* folder with more than about 1000 entries if possible. If there are a lot of filesystem operations that have to use the directory index for a folder that large it can *drastically* reduce filesystem performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$origin = "images/listings";
$final =  "images/final";


$start = strlen($origin) + 1;
$di = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($origin, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
foreach ( $di as $file ) {
    if ($file->isFile()) {
        $mtime = $file->getMTime();
        $date = sprintf("%d/%d/%d", date("Y", $mtime), date("m", $mtime), date("d", $mtime));
        $new = sprintf("%s/%s/%s", $final, $date, substr($file, $start));
        $dir = dirname($new);
        is_dir($dir) or mkdir($dir, null, true);
        rename($file, $new);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the moving of image,you can use the **rename()** Function of php.

For example

> `rename("../app/temp/natural.jpeg","../public/public_photo/natural.jpeg");`

Above given code natural.jpeg from the folder **/aap/temp/** has moved to the folder **/public/public_photo/**